# Iterating over CompactBuffer in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a PairedRDD where values are grouped based on key, from which I fetch a particular key:

```
pairsgrouped.lookup("token")
```

Output:

```
res6: Seq[Iterable[String]] = ArrayBuffer(CompactBuffer(EC-17A5206955089011B, EC-17A5206955089011A))
```

I want to iterate over these values and filter results even further. But I am not able to iterate over it.

I tried the following way:

```
pairsgrouped.lookup("token").foreach(println)
```

But this gives me this:

```
CompactBuffer(EC-17A5206955089011B, EC-17A5206955089011A)
```

I want to iterate over these values and filter the results using these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of your grouped data is an Iterable, not a list of values. You must collect the values first before you can print them. To get only the values for the group with key="token", you do an initial filtering.

```
val result = groupedData.filter{case(key, _) => key == "token"}
                        .values
                        .flatMap(i => i.toList)
                        .collect()

result foreach println
```